# HTML table with drop down box

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-table

I have a table, where I need to ask user to select some data given in a dropdown list with respect to the current cell of the table. After the value selected by the user, when the dropdown list loses its focus, I want to set that value in the same cell as a normal text data. That means the dropdownbox should disappear now and the new value should appear in the same cell as a normal text data.
Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Are you using any programming language besides just regular HTML/CSS?

Comment: this is impossible in simple HTML and CSS.  You need to implement javascript (server side scripting) and a library like JQuery wouldn't be bad either.

Comment: This will require JavaScript, and to make your life easier a tool such as JQuery CSS/HTML are not capable of such a complex task.

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/TBAjV/)?

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS and HTML this is not possible (apart from the most extreme hacking that I can't think of).

The best thing you can use for this probably is Javascript. And as others have suggesting jQuery is a useful library that will make your web development with Javascript easier.